# How can I "batch download" data from Oracle?

Tags: .net, oracle

I'm looking for a tool/technique which is the exact oposite to Oracle Loader. I need to read the whole table with geometries as fast as possible. The application is running on the same machine where Oracle is installed so some kind of "direct" access is possible. The table has around 3 millions records and fetching this amount of data through ordinary client (11 beta -> .Net DevArt Oracle dotConnect driver in OCI mode) takes roughly 6 hours(!). I don't need to execute any queries and the table does not contain any calculated fields or references.

Is it possible?

Comment: How large is the table in Gb?  Are you fetching in OCI one row at a time or in array mode?  6 hours sounds like a very long time for multi row fetching.

Comment: It's not that big - 1.5 Gb. One row at a time, I didn't know you can get data in array mode - thought this was only for pushing data to the Oracle. I'll check dotConnect driver, maybe this functionality is already exposed there. I also suspect that there is something wrong with the client itself (since its 11g BETA) as it slows down significantly after one million records (without any good reason).

Comment: The slowness may not be due to the Oracle Client libraries, but instead your own code as you're storing the results.  If your client is slowing down after a certain point, is it possible that the buffers you're storing your data in have reached their initial capacity, and now your app is being forced to reallocate memory in order to hold the new data?  If your local data structure starts out as N bytes, and has the ability to grow if it exceeds it, it is possible that you would be burning cpu as your structure copies old data to the newly allocated larger block.  It has happened me before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify, do you need to get the data from the oracle table into a flat file? If so Tom Kyte has several examples http://asktom.oracle.com/tkyte/flat/index.html

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Where is the data going ?
If you want an Oracle compatible 'backup' to load into another database, then look at exp or expdp.

Comment: The data is going to a .Net application and is stored in RAM. It's not used for backup or data migration.